# Restore MS SQL Server Database using powershell and task scheduler

Tags: sql-server, powershell, windows-task-scheduler, database-restore

I have a SQL Database that I want to restore nightly on a server that is different from the backup server. I am trying to accomplish this using a powershell script launched at a specific time via task scheduler. I have a powershell script that will restore a MS SQL database:

```bash
$SharedFolder = "C:\Backups"

$RelocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("Database_dat", "C:\Database\XXYYZZ.mdf")

$RelocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("Database_log", "C:\Database\XXYYZZ.ldf")

Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "XXYYZZTEST" -Database "newXXYYZZ" -BackupFile "$($SharedFolder)\tuesday_backup.bak" -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog) -ReplaceDatabase
```

Unfortunately, the first time I run this script in Powershell ISE I receive this red error:

> New-Object : Cannot find type   > [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

for each of the lines $RelocateData and $RelocateLog. The script then fails with this red error:

> Restore-SqlDatabase : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I run the script again without closing Powershell ISE it runs fine on every subsequent run. As soon as I close Powershell ISE  and open it again the error returns on the first run then everything works ok. I have limited knowledge of powershell which hampers my search for a solution to these assembly errors.

It does not successfully run at all when launched from task scheduler but all of the task scheduler actions complete successfully. I have tried running the task as different admin users, highest priority, changing the start in folder. Nothing seemed to help and I suspect it is the issue described above regarding the assemblies.

Any thoughts/suggestions? Is there a better process for accomplishing what I am trying?

Comment: The folder names are not correct.  $SharedFolder does not match the location where files are found.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The $SharedFolder is the location of the backup files. The other folders, $RelocateData and $RelocateLog, are where the database files will reside after restore.

Comment: Solution: Needed Import-Module -Name SqlServer as the first line of my powershell script.

Comment: What do you use in the sign-in page for SQL Server Management Studio?  The login window should show the Server\Instance Name.

Answer (score 1):

Added the line: Import-Module -Name SqlServer to load the powershell module. Script now looks like this:

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer
$SharedFolder = "C:\Backups"
$RelocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("Database_dat", "C:\Database\XXYYZZ.mdf")
$RelocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("Database_log", "C:\Database\XXYYZZ.ldf")
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "XXYYZZTEST" -Database "newXXYYZZ" -BackupFile "$($SharedFolder)\tuesday_backup.bak" -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog) -ReplaceDatabase
```

The script now runs error free in both powershell and task scheduler.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should be able to accept this answer.